Dominant chord -- is its definition super flexible in blues or did I spot a mistake?
I am a beginner, so it may seem like an odd question, but I am reading a book, which is supposed to be written by an expert, and verified by an editor, and yet I cannot make sense of it.
I am evaluating the book "How to Play Blues Piano by Ear", example link. And this caught my eye right from the start:
The author presents a voicing for F7: F, C, D. I scratch my head where D came from. Two half steps below another F would be D#. So the author flattened the last note (IMHO). Ok, next paragraph, voicing of G7: G, D, E. Again, two half steps below the next G would be F, so again the author flattened the last note.
So... is the author correct and there is so much freedom (in general or specific to blues) that you can flatten the last/top note and still call the chord dominant 7th, or is this a mistake and I am not such a total beginner :-)?
I've read the reviews of the book, and it is already mentioned, that the book contains some errors, but judging by their rate, it would be more like "it consists of errors".
Example:

Why not include the name of the book and a few images representing what you are explaining? If this section of the book is for people who are just barely starting out the author might have thought these would be easier voicings (1-5-6) than a more typical voicing (1-5-b7). I still don’t agree with it though.

@JohnBelzaguy I am not sure what you mean by book title, it is really named "How to Play Blues Piano by Ear". I added now an image for clarification.

Apologies, you did include the book title. However seeing this diagram makes the answer clear to me. I will post one soon.

Blues essentially uses 7ths. So F7 would at very least consist of F (R), A (M3) and E♭ (m7). Those notes are key, never mind any extensions. If, as shown, the chord is called F7, then there'll be no D involved. It then, with D, becomes F13, not F7. And the D♯ will be E♭, not the quoted D♯.
The author really ought to explain the thinking behind what's meant, and if they meant D♯ but missed out the sharp sign, more's the pity!
Most Blues will use simply dominant seventh chords, and 13ths very rarely. Try another author!
EDIT: with that extra snippet of information, it's a little (but not much!) clearer. That l.h. 'riff' is/was commonplace, and quite often the G continued, while the D went to E, and then actually to F as well. Making the expected G7!
A prime example which could have been mentioned is Chuck Berry's Memphis Tennessee.

After seeing the diagram you added I was able to figure out that the GDE are not meant to be played together as a chord. They are made to be played GD alternating with GE and usually 2 of each.
A standard blues guitar and piano pattern is to alternate playing Root-5 and a Root-6 over all of the individual chords to a rhythm, usually 8th notes or shuffle 8th notes. This is what is being explained here. This pattern does not contain either a 3rd or b7th and is meant more for rhythmic drive than spelling out the entire harmony. Below is what it looks like in music notation:

Without seeing more of the book or hearing the tracks, I  can’t say if is the specific pattern they are demonstrating but I’m sure it at least is something very similar to what I wrote.

Thank you. But as 7th chord is concerned, "e" note does not come from it, correct? And saying GD is voicing of G7 chord is correct, but it would be also correct it comes from "regular" G chord?

An E note is not part of a G7, no. In this case the E is a neighboring tone of the D. The notes G and D together are not enough to be considered either a G or G7 chord but those two notes are part of both those chords. G and D together is simply called a G5 chord.

With the extra edit, your answer seems the more logical. It's a pity the explanation in the book is so poor - we have to guess that what you wrote is what is meant.

@Tim well, it's probably quite logical when you listen to 'Track 6'. It looks like the book has 'audio access included' but it's complicated to incorporate that into a Stack Exchange question :)

I can't see any music notation in the link, so answering based on what's written in the question.
This is not a double-flat 7th, but rather natural 13. A complete F13 would be F-A-C-Eb-G-(Bb)-D. The voicing F-C-D might not be the most common choice for this chord, but can certainly work. If the 7th (Eb) is consistently not played, the chord may sound less like a dominant F7, and more like a major F6.
Chord symbols typically give some degree of freedom to choose the upper structures and alterations. All depends on the genre, specific song, and the mood you want to achieve.
Moreover, the blues is a very popular form, with a very rich history and familiar for many listeners. It can be transformed and interpreted in various ways.

Thank you. Irony, because in this book there is barely any music notation. For those chords the keyboard diagrams are shown with labels. Now I am tend to think that maybe author was expanding the chords, and then forgot to mention it. Because voicings root+5th (for example) "C G" are labeled as 7th chord (C7 here). But this fits also C as well. F7 and G7 are presented in this manner as well: https://s3.amazonaws.com/halleonard-closerlook/00121704/00121704_Page-3z.jpg

The page you linked instructs the student to vamp on C5, F5 and G5 for a 12-bar blues.  They label the chords as C7, F7, and G7.  I suspect the 5-chords are a temporary simplification, and it'll probably evolve into 7-chords soon.  No sense having a new student stumble over their fingers if that's not the point you're trying to teach.

It's not a voicing for the chord; it's a bass part that goes with the chord.

@phoog right, this context was missing when I was answering the question
